# How to convert my table into a jQuery dataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, flask, datatables

I have two arrays that I had already successfully used to make a table in JavaScript. Now, I would like to make the table a jQuery DataTable because of its UI features. I thought I had the correct way of creating one, but I get an error.

This is also within a Flask app, if that makes a difference

Code

```
<body>
    <!-- Load jQuery -->
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" crossorigin = "anonymous"></script>
    <!-- jQuery dataTables script-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <!-- If that fails, we have a backup in our directory-->
    <script type = text/javascript src = "{{
        url_for('static', filename = 'jquery.js') }}"></script>
    <script type = text/javascript src = "{{
        url_for('static', filename = 'jQuery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- Form for submitting our NBA Data-->
    <form id = "nameForm" role = "form">
        <!-- Input box so we can search by player name -->
        <input name = "text" type = "text" id = "searchBox">
        <!-- Button that we will use to make the actual ajax call -->
        <button id = "searchBtn"> Search </button>
    </form>

    <!-- Container that we will add our data table to later -->
    <table id = "myTable" class = "display" width = "25%"></table>

    <!-- Script for the button click action -->
    <script type = text/javascript> 
        //Root stuff
    $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
    var dataList;
    var titles;
    var dtColumns;

        //Root so we can get the data from our form
        $('button#searchBtn').click(function(e) {
            //Prevent our form from submitting, which is its default action/purpose
            e.preventDefault();
            //Get the data from our function in the Flask App
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_get_data', {
                //Our searchName variable will be the one from our HTML input box
                searchName: $('input[name = "text"]').val(),
            }, function(data) {
                dataList = data.dataList;
                titles = data.headers;
                dtColumns = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                    dtColumns.push({ title : titles[i] });
                }
            });
        }); 
        //When our page is fully loaded, convert the table to a jQuery data table
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable( {
                data: dataList,
                columns: dtColumns  
        });
        })
    </script>


</body>
```

EDIT: The arrays that I am working with, and the newest errors
dtColums is

```
["Player", "Pos", "Age", "Tm", "G", "GS", "MP", "FG", "FGA", "FG%", "3P", "3PA", "3P%", "2P", "2PA", "2P%", "eFG%", "FT", "FTA", "FT%", "ORB", "DRB", "TRB", "AST", "STL", "BLK", "TOV", "PF", "PTS"]
```

And dataList is

```
["James Harden", "SG", "30", "HOU", "7", "7", "35.3", "9.1", "24.0", ".381", "3.4", "13.6", ".253", "5.7", "10.4", ".548", ".452", "14.9", "16.1", ".920", "1.4", "3.7", "5.1", "7.4", "1.0", "0.4", "5.7", "3.6", "36.6"]
```

Current errors that are being returned in a alert in my browser window:

DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Requested unknown parameter '12' for row 0, column 12. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 4, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Answer (score 0):

You are making an async call but not waiting it to return before initializing DataTable. Basically, you are trying to create dataTable from a variable that has not the values you need. You can try to initialize table within callback of getJSON function.

I have not used DataTables for a long time and as I remember I have always written the data to table before initializing but you can try this;

```
    <script type = text/javascript> 
    //Root stuff
$SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
var dataList;
var titles;
var dtColumns;

    //Root so we can get the data from our form
    $('button#searchBtn').click(function(e) {
        //Prevent our form from submitting, which is its default action/purpose
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get the data from our function in the Flask App
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_get_data', {
            //Our searchName variable will be the one from our HTML input box
            searchName: $('input[name = "text"]').val(),
        }, function(data) {
            dataList = data.dataList;
            titles = data.headers;
            dtColumns = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                dtColumns.push({ title : titles[0] });
            }
            $('#myTable').DataTable( {
            data: dataList,
            columns: dtColumns  
            });

        });
    }); 

</script>
```

Comment: That almost works, however, I got 3 errors, one each for a specific cell. I think it’s because those cell’s data start with a number. Is there a way to convert a whole array into only strings in JS?

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing your errors, normally dataTables should be able to handle data starting with numbers but for your question, can you try using Array.map with string constructor which returns a new array.
newDataList = dataList.map(String)

Comment: Will give that a shot, using the array and .toString(); didn’t work

Comment: @RobertSmith If you can post the errors you are receiving with related data or create a fiddle, it would be more useful for me and others to look for possible reasons

Comment: @RobertSmith Is your edited question includes the data with error? This row seems fine to me tbh.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't. Part of the error was having ```titles[0]``` , when I wanted ```titles[i]```. Now I only get one error, but I still don't know what the problem is

Comment: @RobertSmith have you still getting same error or a different one? Maybe you can update the question with the error and related data again. I think that row may includes missing value or assigned null value for some column or columns.

Comment: I get the same error. I just double checked. Same data too

Comment: @RobertSmith But the dataList you shared only contains one row and errors seems to come from different rows. Maybe you can console.log(dataList) at the very end of your script tag and share the log and latest error with me.

Comment: Just logging the list gets Array(29) 2 times, other than that (I moved console.log to after the table was initialized), the errors/data are the same

Comment: So if it says Array(29), you should be able to click that and view inside of that. Your dataList contains 29 elements which means your table will have 29 rows. You can look inside the array from console and find the row which has an error. Your error should contain something like ‘parameter 7 row 13’ and you should find the 13th element from dataList array. Or maybe you can update your question with newest error and full version of dataList by using something like JSON.stringify(dataList)

Comment: Didn’t even know I could click it. I will look into it in a bit and update you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201911/discussion-between-robert-smith-and-theinformedman).